# Draw a single pixel on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, pixel

I'm stuck trying to turn on a single pixel on a Windows Form.

```
graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 50, 50, 51, 50); // draws two pixels

graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 50, 50, 50, 50); // draws no pixels
```

The API really should have a method to set the color of one pixel, but I don't see one.

I am using C#.

Comment: I made a control which plots some very nice scientific graphs (with added capabilities I need not available in any commercial controls).  I can plot a data point with and X or a + or a small box.  But for unimportant data, I just want a single pixel.

Comment: All the answers I see seem like they really are overkill for a single pixel?  Why does it seem easier just to do a buffer[y*width+x]=color;

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This will set a single pixel:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(aBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Who would have guessed that DrawRectangle draws a 2x2 but FillRectange draws a 1x1 with the same arguments?  Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: It does make a sort of sense... DrawRectangle says "draw an outline starting at x and y of this width and height," so it draws both the start and end points (x,y; x+1,y;x,y+1; x+1,y+1) and lines between them.  FillRectangle says "draw a solid surface starting at x,y of this width and height."  Incidentally, FillRectangle takes a Brush, not a Pen.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Actually, it depends on the Pen object you pass to `DrawRectangle()`. If it has `Pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Outset` it will draw `Pen.Width` pixels thick outline round the given rectangle. But if you specify `Pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset` it will draw Pen.Width pixels thick "outline" inside the given rectangle.

Comment: This is a very unsatisfactory answer. Although this sets a single pixel, the requirement is not always to set a literal pixel. All the times I've needed this, which is often, I've needed the dot to be drawn by the same pen that lines are drawn with, not a brush. In other words, we need a line that is shorter that 2 pixels. I suspect that is what the OP needed.

Comment: I don't like this answer. This way is highly inefficient.

Comment: If drawing on graphic with SmoothingMode = AntiAlias, the filled rectangle will start in the middle of the pixel at (x,y) meaning it will draw aliased between 4 pixels. To center the rectangle at (x,y) and thus draw on just the one pixel, subtract 0.5 from x and y. `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(aBrush, x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);`

Answer (score 20):

The `Graphics` object doesn't have this, since it's an abstraction and could be used to cover a vector graphics format. In that context, setting a single pixel wouldn't make sense. The `Bitmap` image format does have `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()`, but not a graphics object built on one. For your scenario, your option really seems like the only one because there's no one-size-fits-all way to set a single pixel for a general graphics object (and you don't know EXACTLY what it is, as your control/form could be double-buffered, etc.)

Why do you need to set a single pixel?

Answer (score 19):

Just to show complete code for Henk Holterman answer:

```
Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

g.FillRectangle(aBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 11):

Where I'm drawing lots of single pixels (for various customised data displays), I tend to draw them to a bitmap and then blit that onto the screen.

The Bitmap GetPixel and SetPixel operations are not particularly fast because they do an awful lot of boundschecking, but it's quite easy to make a 'fast bitmap' class which has quick access to a bitmap.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN Page on GetHdc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z5820hw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I think this is what you are looking for.  You will need to get the HDC and then use the GDI calls to use SetPixel.  Note, that a COLORREF in GDI is a DWORD storing a BGR color.  There is no alpha channel, and it is not RGB like the Color structure of GDI+.

This is a small section of code that I wrote to accomplish the same task:

```
public class GDI
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool SetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int X, int Y, uint crColor);
}

{
    ...
    private void OnPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int renderWidth = GetRenderWidth();
        int renderHeight = GetRenderHeight();
        IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();

        for (int y = 0; y < renderHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < renderWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = GetPixelColor(x, y);

                // NOTE: GDI colors are BGR, not ARGB.
                uint colorRef = (uint)((pixelColor.B << 16) | (pixelColor.G << 8) | (pixelColor.R));
                GDI.SetPixel(hdc, x, y, colorRef);
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The absolute best method is to create a bitmap and pass it an intptr (pointer) to an existing array. This allows the array and the bitmap data to share the same memory... no need to use `Bitmap.lockbits`/`Bitmap.unlockbits`, both of which are slow.

**Here's the broad outline:**

1. Mark your function 'unsafe' and set your projects build settings to allow 'unsafe' code! (C# pointers)
2. Create your `array[,]`. Either using Uint32's, Bytes, or a Struct that permits access to by both Uint32 OR individual Uint8's *(By using explicit field offsets)*
3. Use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.UnsaveAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` to obtain the `Intptr` to the start of the array.
4. Create the Bitmap using the constructor that takes an Intptr and Stride. This will overlap the new bitmap with the existing array data.

You now have permanent direct access to the pixel data!

**The underlying array**

The underlying array would likely be a 2D array of a user-struct `Pixel`. Why? Well... Structs can allow multiple member variables to share the same space by using explicit fixed offsets! This means that the struct can have 4 single-bytes members (`.R`, `.G`, `.B`, and `.A`), and 3 overlapping Uint16's (`.AR`, `.RG`, and `,GB`)... and a single Uint32 (`.ARGB`)... this can make colour-plane manipulations MUCH faster.

As R, G, B, AR, RG, GB and ARGB all access different parts of the same 32-bit pixel you can manipulate pixels in a highly flexible way!

Because the array of `Pixel[,]` shares the same memory as the Bitmap itself, Graphics operations immediately update the Pixel array - and `Pixel[,]` operations on the array immediately update the bitmap! You now have multiple ways of manipulating the bitmap.

Remember, by using this technique you do NOT need to use 'lockbits' to marshal the bitmap data in and out of a buffer... Which is good, because lockbits is very VERY slow.

You also don't need to use a brush and call complex framework code capable of drawing patterned, scalable, rotatable, translatable, aliasable, rectangles... Just to write a single pixel Trust me - all that flexibility in the Graphics class makes drawing a single pixel using `Graphics.FillRect` a very slow process.

**Other benefits**

Super-smooth scrolling! Your Pixel buffer can be larger than your canvas/bitmap, in both height, and width! This enables efficient scrolling!

How?

Well, when you create a Bitmap from the array you can point the bitmaps upper-left coordinate at some arbitrary `[y,x]` coordinate by taking the IntPtr of that `Pixel[,]`.

Then, by deliberately setting the Bitmaps 'stride' to match width of the array *(not the width of the bitmap)* you can render a predefined subset rectangle of the larger array... Whilst drawing *(ahead of time)* into the unseen margins! This is the principle of "offscreen drawing" in smooth scrollers.

**Finally**

You REALLY should wrap the Bitmap and Array into a FastBitmap class. This will help you control the lifetime of the array/bitmap pair. Obviously, if the array goes out of scope or is destroyed - the bitmap will be left pointing at an illegal memory address. By wrapping them up in a FastBitmap class you can ensure this can't happen...

... It's also a really handy place to put the various utilities you'll inevitably want to add... Such as scrolling, fading, working with colour planes, etc.

**Remember:**

1. Creating Bitmaps from a `MemoryStream` is very slow
2. Using `Graphics.FillRect` to draw pixels is painfully inefficient
3. Accessing underlying bitmap data with `lockpixels`/`unlockpixels` is very slow
4. And, if you're using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy`, just stop!

Mapping the Bitmap onto some existing array memory is the way to go. Do it right, and you'll never need/want to use a framework Bitmap again.

Comment: I asked this question 12 years ago, and am still getting answers.
This sounds like a very worthwhile method, and I agree it should
be made into a class... which I would expect you to have already
done.  It would really help if you could post the code for
such a class and save us from "re-inventing the wheel".
(Even if it isn't complete.)

Comment: Working code would be really nice

Answer (score 2):

Drawing a Line 2px using a Pen with DashStyle.DashStyle.Dot draws a single Pixel.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black))
        {
            p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 10, 10, 11, 10);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are drawing on a graphic with SmoothingMode = AntiAlias, most drawing methods will draw more than one pixel. If you only want one pixel drawn, create a 1x1 bitmap, set the bitmap's pixel to the desired color, then draw the bitmap on the graphic.

```
using (var pixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, e.Graphics))
{
    pixel.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pixel, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently DrawLine draws a line that is one pixel short of the actual specified length. There doesn't seem to be a DrawPoint/DrawPixel/whatnot, but instead you can use DrawRectangle with width and height set to 1 to draw a single pixel.

Comment: Nice try, but with size 1 it draws 2x2 pixels.  (Draw it next to a line, and you can see it is twice as wide.)  And with size zero, of course, it draws nothing.

Comment: Right, my mistake. :) Good thing FillRectangle does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code inside the Paint event, otherwise, it will not be refreshed and delete itself.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Red;
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        g.FillRectangle(aBrush, 10, 10, 1, 1);
    }
}
```