# How to draw a single point with .Net?

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

this should be pretty simple but I don't get it. How can I draw a single point in .Net? If I use `g.DrawLine(Black,0,0,0,0)` nothing is drawn and if I use `g.DrawLine(Black,0,0,1,0)` a line with 2 dots is used. The same happens with `g.DrawRectangle`. This has me intrigued.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw a single pixel on Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761003/draw-a-single-pixel-on-windows-forms)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to fill a rectangle which is one pixel wide rather than using a pen:

```
 e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 42, 12, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Rigth, the problem was using DrawRectangle instead of FillRectangle.

Comment: @SoMoS On my machine and every Windows machine I've used in the last fifteen years this has filled a single pixel. Are you sure that your 'proof' is *filling* a 1x1 rectangle, not *drawing* a 1x1 rectangle?

Comment: Just check that I changed the comment before you write that ;)